# How to catch button event for ngx-color-picker?

Tags: angular

Help me please to figure out how can i catch OK button event on ngx-color-picker palette.

There is no appropriate documentation for the events and i hardly believe that this buttons are just decorative. Maybe anyone knows how to handle this. I need to set the color only when the OK button is clicked.

Here is the HTML code part:

```html
<span
  #ignoredInput
  [cpIgnoredElements]="[ignoredButton, ignoredInput]"
  [(cpToggle)]="showPalette"
  [(colorPicker)]="temporaryCustomColor"
  [cpPosition]="'top'"
  [cpCancelButton]="true"
  [cpOKButton]="true"
  [cpSaveClickOutside]="false"
></span>
```

Answer (score 1):

When i was check the [ngx-color-picker](https://github.com/zefoy/ngx-color-picker) [documentation](https://zefoy.github.io/ngx-color-picker/), i saw the `colorPickerSelect` events. When i was check it, it returns you the color code when you click the OK button. May be it can help your for your problem.

Online test code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-vpu5u9?file=projects/app/src/app/app.component.html

Sample Code:

```
  <input
    [value]="color9"
    [style.background]="color9"
    [cpOKButton]="true"
    [cpSaveClickOutside]="false"
    [cpOKButtonClass]="'btn btn-primary btn-xs'"
    [(colorPicker)]="color9"
    (colorPickerSelect)="alert('colorPickerSelect', $event)"
  />
```